# Preg replace get only alphabet

Tags: php, preg-replace

My input **KWT1234KasT123** and my expected output **KWT** but I am getting  **KWTKT**.

I want to stop after the first group of capital letters.
I tried with below code.

```
<?php
 $number = 'KWT1234KasT123';

echo preg_replace_callback('/[^A-Z]+/',function($v){
    $v = str_replace($v, '', $v);
    return $v[0];
  },$number
);
?>
```

Comment: Whats is your criteria for returning KWT?Contiguous capital letters?

Comment: @Mihai thanks for comment. Yes I allowed all capital. I don't know how to give condition here. if get integer then will not continue. Please suggest me.

Comment: Do you want to stop after the first group of capital letters?

Comment: yes that's u get my point @chris85

Comment: Your DEMO returns "KWT".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preg_match` is not global so it will stop after the first match. Try:

```
$number = 'KWT1234KasT123';
preg_match('/[A-Z]+/',$number, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Output:

```
KWT
```

If you wanted to find each grouping of capital letters you could use `preg_match_all`.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to apply preg_match . You really helped me. I was thinking only with preg_replace. :)